# How do I stop connection string from showing on error in Internet Explorer in an Asp.net app?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

Here is what is at the top of the view source page in IE... not good User Name and password showing...

> Data Source=MySource;Initial Catalog=fdic;Persist Security
>   Info=True;User ID=username;Password=mypassword;User
>   Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Pooling=false;Connect
>   Timeout=4000; Exec usp_SYSTEM_CloseSaleSendEmail_db  @id=14888 Invalid
>   object name 'dbo.vwWorkOrderAll'.

Comment: Instead of posting the connection string, post the code that actually writes it to the page. Then remove it. The connection string appears in the page because your code put it there

Answer (score 3):

don't display it.... this is not displayed unless you write to it by either Response.Write or maybe setting a label/literal to the value of the connectionstring. ASP.NET or any other platform does not show connectionstring unless you show it yourself. seems like you have an exception not being caught and handled correctly either thus causing this output. you need to catch and handle the exception correctly.